# Linking external .css file to Html page

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, href

I'm having trouble linking my external file sheet to the separate html page. The .css file and html file are in the same folder also but when i run it the content is only appearing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**CSS Code**

```
div
{
    border-radius:5px;
}

#header
{
    z-index:1;
    width:97.%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position:fixed;
}

#name
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#email
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}


#sidebar
{
    left:90px;
    top:160px;
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:gray;
}

#content
{
    left:290px;
    top:160px;
    position:fixed;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

p
{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css" />
<title>HTML Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainPicture">
        <div class="picture">
            <div id="headerTitle">Project</div>
            <div id="headerSubtext">HTML Project</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="contentBox">
        <div class="innerBox">
            <div class="contentTitle">The Title of an Article</div>
          <div class="contentText"><p>content </p><br />
        <p>Content.</p><br />
          <p>Other Content.</p></div>



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to close you a div after your last <p>s.

Comment: There is no id header or  name or email or sidebar or content on your HTML .... the only style maybe is the padding of the p tag ....

Comment: The id of the element must match with the CSS selectors. i.e if your div id in the HTML is "page" then there must be #page in your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you need. See there please. I noticed lost div , check your code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vo9hLzqf/

If you feel problems with other styles like #email #name etc. check that in HTML you set right type

if your css is #email you should use `<div id="email">%yourcode%</div>`
and .email will be `<div class="email">%yourcode%</div>`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css" />
<title>HTML Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainPicture">
        <div class="picture">
            <div id="headerTitle">Project</div>
            <div id="headerSubtext">HTML Project</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="contentBox">
        <div class="innerBox">
            <div class="contentTitle">The Title of an Article</div>
          <div class="contentText"><p>content </p><br />
        <p>Content.</p><br />
          <p>Other Content.</p></div>


            </div>
</div>
```